# Why after implementing async task, there is still network null exception?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am running on android 3.1 and I have implemented async in my login java class. However, after i implement it in, I got the strict mode exception. Why are there this kind of errors?

Login.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputNric;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;


// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON Response node names
//success is the column name of the database - KEY_SUCCESS is we create the name 
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_NRIC = "nric";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    //StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  //  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputNric = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginNric);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // login button click event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update case
            new LoginUser().execute();
        }
    });

    /*// Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });*/
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to  Login User
 * */
    class LoginUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */        
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging In ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
        * Logging in
        * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                String nric = inputNric.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                Log.d("Button", "Login");
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(nric, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_NRIC), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                      

                            // Launch home Screen
                            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllTabActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching home
                            home.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(home);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            });
                return null;
        }

         /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once case deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }

    }
```

Logcat errors:

```
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at com.pivestigator.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:51)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at com.pivestigator.login.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:40)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at com.pivestigator.login.LoginActivity$LoginUser$1.run(LoginActivity.java:112)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-14 17:46:37.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have doing network operations in runOnUiThread, which will be invoked into event thread, instead you should do as following:

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to  Login User
 * */
    class LoginUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */        
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging In ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
        * Logging in
        * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread
               String nric = inputNric.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                Log.d("Button", "Login");
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(nric, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_NRIC), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                      

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                            // Launch home Screen
                            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllTabActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching home
                            home.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(home);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
}
});
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
        }

         /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once case deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Ohh. I've tried this way too but giving tons of errors.   see here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965046/error-implementing-async-task-in-this-class

Comment: There are syntax error token on the else and syntax error on the  bracket of `} catch (JSONException e)`.